# How can I rent and use my own servers for cloud functions?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I want to use my own servers for cloud functions instead of relying on Google's to eliminate the cold start of functions, how can I do this?

Comment: why use cloud functions if your running your own server?

Comment: @GrantSingleton OP already says in their question: "to eliminate the cold start of functions"

Comment: There are open source products such as Apache OpenWisk and openfaas so that you can build your own Functions/Lambda type of service. Duplicating Google Cloud Functions will all features would not be supported. However, saying that you want to eliminate startup time and be a cloud function is an anti-pattern. To have one, you will have the other. Otherwise it is not a function but part of a larger program/service infrastructure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*firebaser here*

There is currently no native way to run your Cloud Functions on your own server. You **can** run the Firebase emulator suite to emulate functions, but those are not ready for production use.

The more common approach is to set up your own server, using something like Express. But you won't get the other trigger types that Cloud Functions offers, as those are only available within Google's infrastructure at the moment and you'll have to take care of scaling with the load yourself too.