# Firebase Cloud Functions pricing for Admin SDK

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

Is 125k invocations per month for Firebase cloud functions applies to admin-sdk used on custom server? How price of cloud functions is calculated if used with admin sdk on self hosted server?

Answer (score 1):

The 125k invocations per month you are referring to is talking about how many times a Cloud Function is executed/triggered (the term used by Firebase here is invoked). Use of the admin SDK on your own hardware/third-party server doesn't make use of Cloud Functions and is unrelated to the invocation limits.

Let's say you set up a [HTTPS Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events) called `date`. Each time a user visits `https://us-central1-<project-id>.cloudfunctions.net/date`, this would count as 1 invocation of that Cloud Function (ignoring response caching/use of a CDN).

Another example is listening for [new data in Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events#trigger_a_function_when_a_new_document_is_created) that you can call `createUser`. Each time a new `users/someUserID` document is created, the `createUser` function would be invoked.

For such trivial use cases, you aren't likely to hit the 125k limit. But if you have Cloud Functions that deal with frequently modified data or rapidly triggered pub/sub topics, you can quickly approach these limits if care is not taken.

One example of this is if you set up a [RTDB Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events) that was incorrectly listening to any data under `/posts`. Every time a user (or server) changed any data under `/posts`, the function would be invoked. If your cloud function updated `/posts/count` everytime it was called, the cloud function would retrigger itself leading to an infinite loop.

Comment: Can I host cloud functions on my server? Not on GCP?

Answer (score 1):

> Is 125k invocations per month for Firebase cloud functions applies to admin-sdk used on custom server?

Cloud Functions billing is not at all related to whatever billing is incurred by the Admin SDK.  If you use the Admin SDK, you will be billed according to the products it uses, in addition to whatever billing might happen for Cloud Functions.

> How price of cloud functions is calculated if used with admin sdk on self hosted server?

It's not possible to self-host Cloud Functions.  Cloud Functions only runs within Google Cloud infrastructure.

If you use the Admin SDK on your own host, outside of Cloud Functions or any Google Cloud hosting, it does not change the billing compared to the same usage in Cloud Functions.

If you want to know what the cost is for using the Admin SDK, you should understand which product you are accessing with that SDK, and look up its own pricing.  The Admin SDK itself does not bill - it is the usage of the underlying Firebase or Cloud product that incurs billing.

Comment: Can I host cloud functions on my server? Not on GCP?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63230731/how-can-i-rent-and-use-my-own-servers-for-cloud-functions